# Why does my Rear bike tire slow down when Pedaling?

Tags: repair, derailleur-rear, axle, rear-wheel

I just replaced a flat on my rear road-bike tire. I had also tried to replace the rear axle, By removing the axle completely, to a quick release lock but realized the axle that had been installed with the bike tire wasn't hollow so put the old axle back on the bike, seemingly correctly. This morning i went for a ride and when I put any pressure while pedaling it felt as if the rear breaks were engaged. I checked to see what would happen if i pedal with the rear tire in the air and the tire seemed fine but came to a stop more quicker than usual but nothing too alarming.

It seems the problem only occurs when im siting on the bike and there is weight. I also noticed when i pedal the rear derailleur seems to tug forward and hug the rear cog set. im not sure if that's the issue...

Any ideas? I was wanting to save some money by not going to the LBS and learning and doing it myself. But I may have to go anyways.

Here are some images of the bike

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like something wasn't put back together properly. Could do with a photo if you can get one.

Comment: Just uploaded the images @Trengot. Yeah I think maybe something went wrong when i removed the axle... because i've repaired bike tires many many times.

Comment: Do you have your brakes rubbing?

Answer (score 6):

By far the most likely reason is that you've over tightened the bearings.

Did you feel as if you needed 3 hands to get it back together? If not, you did it wrong. :)

As usual [Sheldon](http://sheldonbrown.com/cone-adjustment.html) has a pretty good writeup on this, but the basics are easy enough.

Put one side back together, tighten it up as best you can. Set the cone on the other side to the correct tension. Tighten locknut on second side without turning either cone.

The tricky part is the last bit. You need to hold the cones on both sides at the same time whilst tightening the locknut and you really need 3 hands.

You will most likely have to try a few times to get the tension just right. When it's done it should turn freely but not have any wiggle.

Comment: I found an easier way to do this (before abandoning all "packed bearings" for sealed) Tighten the cone/lock nut on the sprocket side down onto itself, leaving the left side pretty loose (enough to get wrenches into the right side), then tighten down the axel nut (find one if you have a quick release, but OP doesn't). This will lock everything down on the right side (cone, lock nut, axel nut). Now tighten down the left cone and adjust it until the wheel spins freely but not loose. Now hold the cone with a flat wrench and tighten the locknut. Replace the axel nut with quick release if using one

Comment: E second this. It is very likely you overtightened the bearings. These have very low tolerances, and you should tighten then by hand until ensuring there is no movement, and then use a tool ONLY to tighten the hub to the safe locknut. This adjustment can be a pain in older hubs, and i recommend you read the nice tips on the park tool website: http://www.parktool.com/blog/repair-help/hub-overhaul-and-adjustment Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Posible causes:

- The bearings were not repacked properly and they are seizing up under load.
- Your wheel isn't line up properly in the dropouts and your tire is rubbing the chainstay (look for rub marks).
- Your brakes are close enough such that when you pedal the rear end flexes and the brakes touch the rim.

Answer (score -2):

It is the common problem when bearing does not wor properly so you need to change the bearings.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE. We're looking for answers with [more detail](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Other answers cite different possible problems. Please consider expanding your answer to include what led you to this articular conclusion. A short, one-line answer like this is likely to get downvoted, flagged for moderator intervention, and possibly deleted.